# Глобальные границы спрайта не совпадают с отображаемым изображением

Tags: c++, sfml

[image]

```cpp
    void Game::start() 
    { 
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(window_height, window_width), "SnakeHaze");
    apples_ptr = std::unique_ptr<CollectableItem>( new CollectableItem(sf::Vector2f(width_dist(generator), height_dist(generator))) );
    snake = Snake(sf::Vector2f(window_width / 2, window_height / 2), sf::Keyboard::Key::Right);

    sf::RectangleShape apple_box;
    apple_box.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    apple_box.setOutlineThickness(2.f);
    apple_box.setSize(sf::Vector2f(apples_ptr->getGlobalBounds().width, apples_ptr->getGlobalBounds().height));
    apple_box.setPosition(apples_ptr->getPosition());

    sf::RectangleShape snake_box;
    snake_box.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
    snake_box.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    snake_box.setOutlineThickness(2.f);
    snake_box.setSize(sf::Vector2f(snake.getGlobalBounds().width, snake.getGlobalBounds().height));
    snake_box.setPosition(snake.getPosition());

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event window_event;
        while (window.pollEvent(window_event))
        {
            if (window_event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
                snake.update(sf::Keyboard::Left);
            else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
                snake.update(sf::Keyboard::Right);
            else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
                snake.update(sf::Keyboard::Up);
            else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
                snake.update(sf::Keyboard::Down);
        }
        collisionCheck();
        window.clear();
        snake.move();
        window.draw(apple_box);
        window.draw(snake_box);
        window.draw(snake);
        window.draw(*apples_ptr);
        snake_box.setPosition(snake.getPosition());
        window.display();
    }
    }

    void Game::collisionCheck()
    {
    sf::FloatRect nextPos = snake.getGlobalBounds();
    nextPos.left += snake.getSpeed();
    nextPos.top += snake.getSpeed();
    if (apples_ptr->getGlobalBounds().intersects(nextPos))
    {
        apples_ptr.reset();
        apples_ptr = std::unique_ptr<CollectableItem>(new CollectableItem(sf::Vector2f(width_dist(generator), height_dist(generator)))); // Создаем новый объект на случайных координатах
    }
    }
```

Границы спрайта не совпадают с границами изображения.
Проект https://github.com/Queshema123/SnakeHaze/tree/master

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы имеете в виду, я на вашем скриншоте вижу, что синие box'ы выступают из спрайтов на величину, заданную вами в setOutlineThickness - всё как и должно быть

Comment: Посмотрел картинки на гитхабе - они в точности такого же размера, как и белые-жёлтые box'ы на вашем скриншоте, так что непонятно в чём проблема-то

Comment: Те квадраты, которые изображены на скриншоте, границы данных спрайтов, из-за этого соприкосновение между ними происходит раньше чем касаются их изображения

Comment: Как я уже отметил в предыдущем комментарии, размеры этих квадратов точно совпадают с размерами изображений, так что до сих пор непонятно в чём проблема

Comment: Размеры данных квадратов установлены по размеру глобальных границ данных спрайтов, проблема в том, что данный размер не совпадает с размером изображения ни яблока, ни змеи. Мне бы хотелось либо как-то изменить фактические размеры либо глобальных границ, либо настроить корректное отображение картинки, т.е чтобы границы совпадали с изображением и соприкосновение (См. функцию collisionCheck) срабатывало при соприкосновение картинок

Comment: Прошу прощения за свою глупость, проблема была в самой картинке, при нарисовании ее программа оставляла не заполненное пространство пустым, из-за чего изображение не сопвпадало с его фактическим размером.